# Error on start HBase on Windows with Cygwin : Could not find the main class : org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster

Tags: java, cygwin, hbase

I followed this : http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html.
Each step is ok until the start of HBase.
It's perhaps a path problem between Windows and Cygwin, but I am lost ...

Comment: Please be more specific. What's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that, when I start HBase, there is the error I put in the title of this post.

Comment: I have just found the solution here : http://ics.upjs.sk/~novotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows. In conf/hbase-env.sh I uncommented and modified the line : 

export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase-0.94.12/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar

Comment: Humm ... I can't close this question ...

Comment: No need to close. Answer it and verify as useful.

Answer (score 0):

The person who asked the question commented with the below answer

> I have just found the solution [here](http://ics.upjs.sk/%7Enovotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows)
>
> In `conf/hbase-env.sh` uncomment and modify the line
>
> `export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase-0.94.12/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar`